# How to group all anagrams together using a custom comparator function?

Tags: c++

So, I am developing a logic for grouping all anagrams together using a custom comparator in the sort function which will return true only when the strings are both anagrams which can be easily checked if the sorted versions of the strings are equivalent. I developed the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
bool mycomp (const string &a1, const string &a2);
#define N 5
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    string arr[50];
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    sort(arr,arr+N,mycomp);
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

bool mycomp (const string &a1, const string &a2)
{
    string f1 = sort(a1.begin(),a1.end());
    string f2 = sort(a2.begin(),a2.end());
    return (f1 == f2);
}
```

Now, this code doesn't compile and shows the error that string cannot be passed in mycomp.. And shows a lot of errors. Also, is my logic correct? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_comp` should be:

```
bool mycomp (std::string a1, std::string a2)
{
    std::sort(a1.begin(), a1.end());
    std::sort(a2.begin(), a2.end());
    return a1 < a2;
}
```

as `std::sort` modifies the string, if you pass const references, you have to create a copy for the sort.

Comment: I have two doubts. First, if I just remove the `const`, then why won't it work? Because I am passing references to two string, can't I use them directly for sorting the strings? And secondly, why can't I return `return a1==a2`, i.e. if they will be equal, it will return true else false.

Comment: the comparator should return 0 between equal elements

Comment: It should return true between equal elements, right? So, if I do, `return a1==a2`, it will return true. And also, why can I not use references here?

Comment: @Daniele: `return 0` logically doesn't make sense, the return type is boolean. But `return false` is indeed correct for equal elements. And that's in fact what the code above returns. `a1 < a1` is always false.

Comment: @Elliot: No, you need a partial order. If you only know which elements are equal, you still wouldn't know which comes first.

Comment: @MSalters, so I wrote a comparator. Now, as far as I understand, what a comparator does is in this case, if `a1 < a2` is true, then `a1` will go before in the sorted array else `a1` will go after in the sorted array. Right? Now, if both the strings are equal, it will return false meaning, that, the equal string won't go after one another?

Comment: Also, what does a string less than other string actually mean? Does it mean a string's ASCII value is less than other string's ASCII value?

Comment: @MSalters, yes sorry. I meant 'false'.

Comment: @Elliot: You're incorrectly inverting the statement. If `a1<a2` then a1 goes before a2. If `a2<a1` then a2 goes before a1. If neither is the case, the order is **unspecified**. See also `stable_sort`, which will leave a1 and a2 in their input order if such cases. As for strings being less than another, it approximately means "alphabetically but case-sensitive".

Comment: @MSalters, I am still not clear why we are returning a1 < a2. I mean I got it why we wont return a1==a2 because we wont know, which element goes first. But then why does a1 < a2 work?

Comment: @Elliot: Because that's the sort of comparison that `std::sort` expects. It's really that simple.